# How to pass multi-input data loader to single-input model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have the following code that works fine. But the problem is that it works only on one batch because I am using `next(iter)`

I created a tensorflow dataset that must return 3 values (i.e. `X: [x,y,z]`) for my problem. But I need to pass only the `x` value to the model. And I need to keep all 3 values packed together as I will be using `y` and `z` later. Now, the thing is that when I am going to call `fit`, I have to somehow separate those 3 values in order to call properly the network architecture. So, my problem is how to call `fit` using the `PrefetchDataset` in such scenarios.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense,  Activation, \
    Conv2DTranspose, Conv2D, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

def scale(X, a=-1, b=1, dtype='float32'):
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a
    xmin = tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_min(X), dtype=dtype)
    xmax = tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_max(X), dtype=dtype)
    X = (X - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)
    scaled = X * (b - a) + a
    return scaled, xmin, xmax

def set_shape_b(x, y, z):
    x = tf.reshape(x,  [16, 16, 2])
    y = tf.reshape(y, [1])
    z = tf.reshape(z, [1])
    return x, y, z

def set_shape_a(x, y, z):
    x = tf.reshape(x,  [4, 4, 2])
    y = tf.reshape(y, [1])
    z = tf.reshape(z, [1])
    return x, y, z

def First(lr):
    inp = Input(lr)
    x = Dense(16)(inp)
    x = Reshape((4, 4, 16))(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(2, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2DTranspose(2, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    output = Activation('tanh')(x)
    model = Model(inp, output, name='First')
    return model
    
def Second(hr):
    inp = Input(hr)
    x = Dense(16)(inp)
    x = Conv2D(2, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(2, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=output, name='Second')
    return model
    

def build_model(First, Second):
    inp = Input(shape=INP)
    gen = First(inp)
    output = Second(gen)
    model = Model(inputs=inp , outputs=[gen, output], name='model')
    return model

# Preproces --------------- #
a = np.random.random((20, 4, 4, 2)).astype('float32')
b = np.random.random((20, 16, 16, 2)).astype('float32')

dataset_a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a)
dataset_b = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(b)

dataset_b = dataset_b.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(scale,
                                                   [x], 
                                                   (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32)))
dataset_b = dataset_b.map(set_shape_b)

dataset_a = dataset_a.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(scale,
                                                   [x], 
                                                   (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32)))
dataset_a = dataset_a.map(set_shape_a)
 
dataset_ones = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.ones((len(b), 4, 4, 1)))   

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_a, (dataset_b, dataset_ones)))

dataset = dataset.cache()
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

# Prepare models -------------------- #
INP = (4, 4, 2)
OUT = (16, 16, 2)

first = First(INP)
second = Second(OUT)
model = build_model(first, second)

model.compile(loss=['mse', 'binary_crossentropy'],
              optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4))


train_l, (train_h, train_ones) = next(iter(dataset))


# train ------------------
model.fit(train_l[0],
          [train_h[0], train_ones],
          epochs=2)
```

**UPDATE**

```
def rescale(X_scaled, xmin, xmax):
    X = (xmax - xmin) * (X_scaled + 1) / 2.0 + xmin
    return X

class PlotCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, image, xmin, xmax, model):
        self.image = image
        self.xmin = xmin
        self.xmax = xmax
        self.model = model
        
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        preds = self.model.predict(self.image)
        y_pred = preds[0]
        y_pred = rescale(y_pred, self.xmin, self.xmax)

        
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 10))
        ax.imshow(y_pred[0][:, :, 0])
        plt.close()
```

I am using the above functions and when trying to fit I want sth like that:

```
model.fit(
    dataset,
    validation_data=dataset,
    epochs=2,
    callbacks=[PlotCallback(here_the_dataset_a_scaled_values,
                            xmin_from_dataset_a,
                            xmax_from_dataset_b, model)]
)
```

Comment: The problem I can see is the in your dataset, i.e. `train_l` it returns 3 value (scale, min, max) and your build your model in a way to take one scale. For that you tried to use first index of `train_l` while calling fit.

Comment: Also, your model is kinda sequentail type model. There is no multi output but still you did `zip((dataset_a, (dataset_b, dataset_ones)))` why? By looking at your model definition, It looks like you don't need `dataset_b`.

Comment: @Innat:yes, that is the problem. I just used the first batch. I can't just use the whole dataset, because it contains all values, (scale, min, max) and tf.ones.  I want to find a solution.

Comment: @Innat: I need `dataset_b`. It is used as `train_h`  argument. I just posted a minimal example here, that's why we have this model setup.

Comment: @Innat:Yes, `build_model` as you can see, has 1 input and 2 outputs `Model(inputs=inp , outputs=[gen, output], name='model')`.  My data loading pipeline , gives the `X` and `y` for model training. I want to keep this dataset output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment above, to resolve your issue you can apply custom function to return only the target values. Also, take a look at [tf.data.Dataset.map](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) for references.

```py
def set_shape(x, y, z, dims):
    x = tf.reshape(x,  dims)
    y = tf.reshape(y, [1])
    z = tf.reshape(z, [1])
    return x, y, z

dataset_a = dataset_a.map(lambda x, y, z: set_shape(x, y, z, dims=[4, 4, 2]))
dataset_b = dataset_b.map(lambda x, y, z: set_shape(x, y, z, dims=[16, 16, 2]))

def only_scale(x, y, z):
    return x

dataset_a = dataset_a.map(only_scale)
dataset_b = dataset_b.map(only_scale)
```

Zipping and batch the data.

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(
    (dataset_a, (dataset_b, dataset_ones))
)
dataset = dataset.cache()
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

a, b = next(iter(dataset)) 
a.shape, b[0].shape, b[1].shape
(TensorShape([2, 4, 4, 2]),
 TensorShape([2, 16, 16, 2]),
 TensorShape([2, 4, 4, 1]))
```

Now, we can pass it to fit method.

```py
# train ------------------
model.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=2
)

Epoch 1/2
2s 6ms/step - loss: 1.0283 - First_loss: 0.3368 - Second_loss: 0.6914
Epoch 2/2
0s 4ms/step - loss: 1.0228 - First_loss: 0.3367 - Second_loss: 0.6860
```

### Update 1

As it is mentioned in the comment, `.map(only_scale)` can not be used in order to receive `(scale, xmin, xmax)` for un-scaling in the middle of training. But we can't pass such data format to model that doesn't expect such input specificaiton. In other word, the model code has no idea about `xmin` and `xmax`.

In such case, there are two option to resolve it. One is to use custom training loop in keras and another one is to override the `train_step` function of `fit` method. Let's try the second one. In that case, we don't need to use `.map(only_scale)` method from data APIs. Here is the [references](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/) about override the fit method.

Let's build a custom model to override the `trian_step` and (also `test_step` for validation data). FYI, there is also `predict_step`.

```py
class CustomFitter(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, model, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.model = model 
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.model(inputs)
    
    def unpack(self, data):
        x, y = data
        # x: dataset_a
        # y: (dataset_b, dataset_ones)
        # dataset_a / datast_b: (scale, xmin, xmax)
        scale_y = y[0][0]
        ones_y = y[1]
        y = (scale_y, ones_y)
        x = x[0]
        return x, y
    
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = self.unpack(data)
        return super().train_step((x, y))
    
    def test_step(self, data):
        x, y = self.unpack(data)
        return super().test_step((x, y))
```

Next, we can do

```py
model = build_model(first, second)
model = CustomFitter(model)
model.compile(
    loss=['mse', 'binary_crossentropy'],
    optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
)
```

Next, we can now fit the datast (without using `only_scale` method).

```py
model.fit(
    dataset,
    validation_data=dataset,
    epochs=2
)
```

```py
Epoch 1/2
45ms/step - loss: 1.0278 - output_1_loss: 0.3358 - output_2_loss: 0.6919 - val_loss: 1.0262 - val_output_1_loss: 0.3357 - val_output_2_loss: 0.6905
Epoch 2/2
8ms/step - loss: 1.0249 - output_1_loss: 0.3356 - output_2_loss: 0.6893 - val_loss: 1.0234 - val_output_1_loss: 0.3355 - val_output_2_loss: 0.6879
```

### Update 2

Regarding the use of `xmin` and `xmax` in callback to rescale prediction array and plotting, we can do somethings as follows.

1. We will store the valus of `xmin` and `xmax` at the training time. We will store these values from validation data set for now.
2. Later in callback we use this values at `on_epoch_end` and reset at `on_epoch_begin` for the next epoch.

At first we will do:

```py
from tensorflow.experimental import numpy as tnp

with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
    scaling_xmin = tf.Variable(
        tnp.empty((0, 1), dtype=tf.float32), shape=[None, 1], trainable=False
    )
    scaling_xmax = tf.Variable(
        tnp.empty((0, 1), dtype=tf.float32), shape=[None, 1], trainable=False
    )
```

```py
class CustomFitter(keras.Model):
    ....
    
    def unpack(self, data, data_src='valid'):
        x, y = data
        # x: dataset_a
        # y: (dataset_b, dataset_ones)
        # dataset_a / datast_b: (scale, xmin, xmax)
        
        if data_src == 'valid':
            scaling_xmin.assign(
                tf.concat([scaling_xmin, x[1]], axis=0)
            )
            scaling_xmax.assign(
                tf.concat([scaling_xmax, x[2]], axis=0)
            )
        
        scale_y = y[0][0]
        ones_y = y[1]
        y = (scale_y, ones_y)
        x = x[0]
        return x, y

    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = self.unpack(data, data_src='train')
        return super().train_step((x,y))
    
    def test_step(self, data):
        x, y = self.unpack(data, data_src='valid')
        return super().test_step((x, y))
```

Now, in callback, we will do

```py
class PlotCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, image):
        self.image = image
        
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        scaling_xmin.assign(
            tf.Variable(
                tnp.empty((0,1), dtype=tf.float32), shape=[None,1]
            )
        )
        scaling_xmax.assign(
            tf.Variable(
                tnp.empty((0,1), dtype=tf.float32), shape=[None,1]
            )
        )

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        preds = self.model.predict(self.image)
        y_pred = preds[0]
        
        # assuming y_pred.shape[0] == xmin.shape[0] == xmax.shape[0]
        for yp, xmin, xmax in zip(
            y_pred, scaling_xmin.numpy(), scaling_xmax.numpy()
        ):
            yp = rescale(
                yp, xmin, xmax
            )
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 10))
            ax.imshow(yp[:, :, 0])
            break
        plt.show()
```

Next, we can call this callback. Note, we are passing 2D single input. If the `PlotCallback(dataset)` is passed, make sure to implement `predict_step`, that would be almost same as `test_step` in above model code.

```py
a = np.random.random((20, 4, 4, 2)).astype('float32')
custom_model.fit(
    dataset,
    validation_data=dataset,
    callbacks=[PlotCallback(a)],
    epochs=2
)
```

```py
107ms/step - loss: 1.0251 - output_1_loss: 0.3387 - output_2_loss: 0.6864 - val_loss: 1.0239 - val_output_1_loss: 0.3386 - val_output_2_loss: 0.6853

[plot will be displayed]
```

### Update 3

As you mentioned in the comment, at first the log names in the display were `First_loss`, `Second_loss` and after update 1/2, it becomes the `output_1_loss` and `output_2_loss`. To fix this, we can change the model code a bit. First, we would do

```py
def build_model(First, Second):
    inp = Input(shape=INP)
    gen = First(inp)
    output = Second(gen)
    return inp, [gen, output]
```

Next, we do as follows to the `CustomFitter`, remove the init and call method, not needed anymore.

```py
class CustomFitter(keras.Model):
    def unpack(self, data, data_src='valid'):
        ...
        return x, y
    
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = self.unpack(data, data_src='train')
        return super().train_step((x,y))
    
    def test_step(self, data):
        x, y = self.unpack(data, data_src='valid')
        return super().test_step((x, y))


first = First(INP)
second = Second(OUT)
inputs, outputs = build_model(first, second)
custom_model = CustomFitter(inputs, outputs)
custom_model.compile(
    loss=[
        'mse', 
        'binary_crossentropy'
    ],
    optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
)
```

```
loss: 1.0337 - First_loss: 0.3405 - Second_loss: 0.6932 - val_loss: 1.0330 - val_First_loss: 0.3404 - val_Second_loss: 0.6926
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help.Unfortunately, I need to receive the `(scale, xmin, xmax)`. Because i want to use the xmin, xmax for un-scaling. That's why I have this mess.. Because I need to return xmin and xmax also.

Comment: Uh, I see. I think that's also possible with bit of work. We can customize the fit method, so that in the training step, only the scale value is passed and not xmin xmax. I will update my answer.

Comment: Updated. Take a look. One issue might be feel like the names in the logs. Let me know if it's an issue to you.

Comment: Also, what about the min and max values? For example I want to use the min and max values from the test set.

Comment: I don't know how you would use xmin or xmax. In your code there is no demonstraiton of that. Like where to use that!

Comment: I updated my post at the end. I want to use xmin and xmax for plotting the re-scaled arrays. And generally, when I will predict a new dataset, I must be able to extract those min, max values to apply rescale.

Comment: Of course, where I have `dataset_a` in the callback, in reality it will be the unknown `test` set.

Comment: Please ensure this, the xmin and xmax would be static and fixed values in actual cases, right? In the above code, they're generated from `np.random.random` method ans so each call will produce different xmin and xmax. But in actual case these value should be fixed values, right?

Comment: Also, the value of xmin and xmax will be extract from validation data set and will be used in prediction data set, right?

Comment: Yes, we will have fixed arrays, so the xmin and xmax when calling `scale` will be fixed.And we need them in order to revert back to original array.

Comment: I apply scale to `dataset_a`, `dataset_b` . Then, I create the `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_a, (dataset_b, dataset_ones)))` which contains all scaled and xmin , xmax values. Later, (I am not doing this in this example code) , I split the dataset into train, val, test sets. So, each set contains, `(scaled, xmin, xmax)`.  And I need the `xmin , xmax` for `val` and `test` sets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253719/discussion-between-innat-and-george).